# How to know whether a calling convention is in use with a Qt project?

Tags: c++, templates, calling-convention

You know, when you define a function, you can define it's calling convention at the same time, like this:

```
int __stdcall foo(int) { return 1; };
int __cdecl   bar(int) { return 1; };
```

And if you want to use this function to deduce template parameters, you have to deal with the calling convention, eg:

```
template<typename T> void tmpl_func( T( __stdcall f )(T) ) { other_func<T>(); };
```

With this template, you can only use "**foo**" as the parameter. If you use "**bar**", it can't be compiled.

```
tmpl_func(foo);   // ok
tmpl_func(bar);   // err
```

So, if you have a function that uses **__cdecl**, you have to define the template functions with both calling conventions, like this:

```
template<typename T> void tmpl_func( T( __stdcall f )(T) ) { other_func<T>(); };
template<typename T> void tmpl_func( T( __cdecl   f )(T) ) { other_func<T>(); };
```

And **foo** instantiate the **__stdcall** version, **bar** instantiate  the **__cdecl** version, no redefinition.

In general, this works well, but recently i met a problem:

In a Qt project, when i define template functions in the way i said above, the compiler said :**__cdecl** template function has already defined.

And if you only define **tmpl_func** in **__stdcall** version, it also can use **bar** as it's parameter.

Is this means that all the calling convention identifiers i wrote just dont work, and all functions are called in **__cdecl** way?

Why and how could i know whether this situation will happen?  Can i check it using macros or compile options?

Sorry for my bad english, I wish i had made it clear, but this do troubles me for some time.

Comment: You don't explain why you need to use `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`. I believe it is a huge mistake to use it and in practice you certainly should *not* use that in templates.

Comment: A calling convention is always in use. Are you asking how to tell *which* convention applies?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  just do some meta program.  i found that i have to add calling conventions so that my template functions could resolve the function i used as a parameter correct.

Comment: @EJP no. i just use it to resolve template parameters. i found that if i don't specify the calling convention explicitly, template call fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You know, when you define a function, you can define it's calling convention at the same time

This is wrong. What you describe is a (vendor specific) extension to C++. For example, on my [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler on Linux, it probably won't work.

> In a Qt project,

**Don't use at all any *explicit* `__stdcall` or `__cdecl` annotation in your Qt code.**

<sup>(using that in your Qt code is shooting yourself in your foot: it hurts badly; stick to standard C++11 code for a Qt5 project)</sup>

If you need to call some *external* weird function (with a strange & *explicit* calling convention) write some `extern "C"`  (or some `static inline` one, if it is short) wrapping function doing that (and your wrapping function has a usual signature, without explicit calling convention annotation).

Pragmatically, when coding a Qt project, you compile it with all warnings & debug info (so `g++ -Wall -g` if using GCC), you debug it with your `gdb` debugger, and you later optimize (e.g. compile with `g++ -Wall -g -O2`) it -e.g. for benchmarking and production code- and you trust the compiler to optimize well, inline many function calls, and choose good enough calling conventions. Don't mess with calling conventions in your Qt code.

<sup>(implicitly you are asking if and how `__stdcall` or `__cdecl` is changing the type system of C++; and C++ types are complex enough already, you don't want even more mess)</sup>